# Cypher method for openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, encryption

I have a question regarding cypher methods on AWS.
Is AES256-GCM-SHA384 as stated on AWS documentation site same as AES-256-GCM which I get when I run openssl_get_cipher_methods() locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AES256-GCM-SHA384` from the AWS supported cipher suite, is using `AES-256` in `GCM` mode to encrypt data, where `SHA384` is used for HMAC & PRF.

With regard to `AES-256-GCM`, when a `HMAC` isn't stipulated, `GHASH` the native `AES-GCM` `MAC` primitive is used.

So in summary, very similar, but AWS uses `SHA` and `AES-256-GCM` uses `GHASH`.

Comment: So, if I add AES-256-GCM to my openssl_encrypt function, AWS will not complain?

Comment: TLS cipher suite negotiation will select a cocktail of primitives, they have to match. The selection of this is part of the protocol. If AWS expects SHA for MAC and gets GHASH it won't work.

Comment: So it must be AES256-GCM-SHA384 , precisely?

Comment: yup, the SHA function here will be used to hash the shared secret/as a PRF, both sides of the rx/tx need to match on primitives